# SQL select everything with arbitrary IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

This will sound silly, but trust me it is for a good (i.e. over-engineered) cause.

Is it possible to write a SQL query using an IN clause which selects everything in that table without knowing anything about the table?  Keep in mind this would mean you can't use a subquery that references the table.

In other words I would like to find a statement to replace "SOMETHING" in the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE table_a.id IN (SOMETHING)
```

so that the results are identical to:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a
```

by doing nothing beyond changing the value of "SOMETHING"

---

To satisfy the curious I'll share the reason for the question.

1) I have a FactoryObject abstract class which grants all models that extend it some glorious [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) magic using two [template methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern): getData() and load()

2) Models must implement the template methods. getData is a static method that accepts ID constraints, pulls rows from the database, and returns a set of associative arrays. load is not static, accepts an associative array, and populates the object based on that array.

3) The non-abstract part of FactoryObject implements a getObject() and a getObjects() method.  These call getData, create objects, and loads() the array responses from getData to create and return populated objects.

getObjects() requires ID constraints as an input, either in the form of a list or in the form of a subquery, which are then passed to getData().  I wanted to make it possible to pass in no ID constraints to get all objects.

The problem is that only the models know about their tables. getObjects() is implemented at a higher level and so it doesn't know what to pass getData(), unless there was a universal "return everything" clause for IN.

There are other solutions.  I can modify the API to require getData to accept a special parameter and return everything, or I can implement a static getAll[ModelName]s() method at the model level which calls:

```
static function getAllModelObjects() {
    return getObjects("select [model].id from [model]");
}
```

This is reasonable and may fit the architecture anyway, but I was curious so I thought I would ask!

Comment: how about where (table_a.id in ('blah') or 1=1)?  Actually... fits the criteria as it uses an "IN" clause but also an OR :D  still thinking

Comment: Ok, I'm quite interested in knowing the purpose of this now...

Comment: any reason not to be able to put a subquery in there? like in `SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE table_a.id IN (SELECT id FROM table_a)` ?

Comment: @Pavel aside from he said that wans't acceptable? :D

Comment: @xQbert, you're right. my bad :)

Comment: How about if SQL injection is used... Select * from table_A ID in (';Select ID from Table_A--'  but personally I like the not in; but it changes too much of your premise.

Comment: smells smells smells. Seriously, it would be interesting why you need a such things instead of `SELECT * FROM table_a`. I suspect a corporate framework :-)

Comment: Maybe with more information we can help you find another workaround, but as I just edited my answer to point out... it's not possible :/

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks to everyone for playing around with this brain teaser!  Hopefully it wasn't too frustrating -- also I'll really consider the use of injection attacks, but I think that working the political chain and getting the MySQL team to add a new feature would be a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I hate saying no so I had to come up with another solution for you.

Since mysql is opensource you can get the source and incorporate a new feature that understands the infinity symbol.  Then you just need to get the mysql community to buy into the usefulness of this feature (steer the conversation away from security as much as possible in your attempts to do so), and then get your company to upgrade their dbms to the new version once this feature has been implemented.

Problem solved.

Comment: Hey, I just think they need to stop using parameterized queries and introduce some SQL injection... problem solved.  far simpler than getting Open source community to buy in and easy enough to get a new programmer to make that mistake... :D

Comment: @xQbert I can see we're on the same wavelength here :)

Comment: So to be precise something would be `'1')  OR 1=1;--` and SQL injection would be required.

Comment: Maybe you should post that as an answer just in case he gets lucky and it works...

Comment: Haha, I have to give you a credit for this answer :-) This is the perfect fit for this question ! Garbage in garbage out :D

Comment: Perhaps; but the silly factor is over now :D  The viable, reasonable, and unreasonable answers have been provided.  We've explored both the in the box and "What box" answers.  The correct answer is can't be done;  However, there are several 'hacks' and truly out there (lets redesign open source... WTH...) options as well but they are eh hem... lets just say not so correct.

Comment: @prajeeshkumar that's not nice!  I explicitly ask if it's possible, knowing it might not be -- who are you to decide why someone would want to do it ;)

Comment: @slifty Agreed.  No dumb questions... just dumb people who don't ask them.

Comment: @slifty There are few things that are reasonable and few things that aren't. You didn't provide your constraints first and even when you were told an answer by evanc3 you simply said you cant refer the same table, still you didnt tell why !  wouldn't you be rather nice to someone who provided you an answer and tell the reason ?

Comment: @slifty every one who provided answers would have also spent atleast 10 minutes themselves, totalling much more than what you have spent and that also not for their cause :D  Why this did look like bad to me is that you didn't get a `select * from <table>` feature when you got a `select * from <table> where id in(<id>)` feature. (May be there is something like if you pass `null` for the id it will select all)  Ok, ok, i am not the `who` to decide why some thing is like something :)

Answer (score 4):

Works on SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE table_a.id IN (table_a.id)
```

Comment: Can't reference the table in the subquery though :/

Comment: The constraints of the problem state that you can't reference the table in question :(  Sorry for being such a trickster!

Comment: I'm curious does the execution plan show this as a sub select?  if not... well then... it passes!

Comment: @xQbert The visual representations actually look identical.  While this does technically violate the stipulations of the question, this could possibly work... if it weren't for the fact that he then expounded to say that getObjects() is ignorant of the finer details and probably wouldn't know the name of the table... which of course just means the OP knew what he was talking about when he said the subquery couldn't reference the table.

Comment: That is, the visual representations of the execution plan in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. The workaround is to add some criteria like these:

```
# to query on a number column
AND (-1 in (-1) OR sample_table.sample_column in (-1))  

# or to query on a string column
AND ('%' in ('%') OR sample_table.sample_column in ('%'))
```

Therefore, in your example, two following queries should return the same result as soon as you pass -1 as the parameter value.

```
SELECT * FROM table_a;
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE (-1 in (-1) OR table_a.id in (-1));
```

And whenever you want to filter something out, you can pass it as a parameter. For example, in the following query, the records with id of 1, 2 and 6 are filtered.

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE (-1 in (1, 2, 6) OR table_a.id in (1, 2, 6));
```

In this case, we have a default value like -1 or % and we have a parameter that can be anything. If the parameter is the default value, nothing is filtered.

I suggest % character as the default value if you are querying over a text column or -1 if you are querying over the PK of the table. But it totally depends to you to substitute % or -1 with any reserved character or number that you decide on.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select * from table_a where table_a.id not ine ('somevaluethatwouldneverpossiblyexistintable_a.id')
```

EDIT:

As much as I would like to continue thinking of a way to solve your problem, I know there isn't a way to so I figure I'll go ahead and be the first person to tell you so I can at least get credit for the answer.  It's truly a bittersweet victory though :/

If you provide more info though maybe I or someone else can help you think of another workaround.

Comment: You probably thought of that already, but just in case I thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: sadly I have no control over the original query -- the only thing I can do is change the statement "SOMETHING."  I'll make that more clear in the question.

Comment: Blast.  I suspected there was no way -- I can think of a workaround (and will share the reason as an edit to the question shortly just to satisfy curiosities) but I wanted to hear the bad news from someone else.  I was really hoping there was a secret undocumented wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

similiar to @brandonmoore:

```
select * from table_a where table_a.id not in ('0')
```